# "Loading video..." seems to take forever on Android

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

For some reason, whenever I try to stream a video on my Galaxy S3 (running the latest stable Cyanogenmod 10) it takes up to 1 minute before it eventually starts playing. The exact same video on my iPad will load instantly on the exact same connection.

Does anyone please know why this is? I usually play videos through the default app, 'Gallery' I think it is, but I have tried other players too (ie MX Player and Hubi) and get the same problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Their could be a number of possible problems such as the format of the video; either the phones hardware or Cyanogenmod 10 may not support the format in which the video is in. I believe the video format is most likely the case because as you describe:

> The exact same video on my iPad will load usually instantly on the exact same connection.

and

> I usually play videos through the default app, 'Gallery' I think it is, but I have tried other players too (ie MX Player and Hubi) and get the same problem.

So check the video format of the videos in which you view. [In this link, they describe the possible video formats that the Galaxy S3 can play](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-I9300MBDBTU-spec). If the video is not in the correct format, I suggest trying to convert the video files localy on your PC.

Also another solution may be to re-image the phone to possibly earlier version of Cyanogenmod could possibly work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it happens across many different sites though in what I believe are different formats. The video does play eventually (sorry I didn't make that clear in the original post) it just takes ages to start.

Comment: @Nick That is quite alright, just be sure to edit the original post.